# Setting up Xamarin.Forms & Visual Studio 2019 to pair to mac ISSUE

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

> An unexpected error occurred while checking the SSH configuration of
>   `IP Address`. Could not find a part of the path 
>   `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\hosts.key`

I was able to SSH log in from CMD to the Macbook, but I'm unable to pair the mac to Visual Studio (VS) 2019. I've VS and xcode installed. The emulator works on VS on the mac. Why can't I pair the MAC to my windows PC. Am I supposed to create the MonoTouch folder & hosts.key?

What is the process to do this?

P.S. I understand I can do everything on the Mac, but I prefer my PC set up for development purposes.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by creating MonoTouch folder and then going to *Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts* and trying to connect.

Comment: Just experienced this myself, creating the dir manually fixes the problem. This sounds like a bug, did you already report it?

Comment: Creating the path manually fixed it for me - I've reported the issue

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by creating the folder manually.

1. Go to:
   `C:\Users\myuserhere\AppData\Local\Xamarin\`
2. Then create the folder manually
   `C:\Users\myuserhere\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\`

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error message. I deleted all the content of the folder **C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch*.***

I believe the issue was caused by a newer version installed on the MAC.

After deleting the content of the folder above and trying to **Pair to Mac** in **Visual Studio 2019 (PC)**, I was prompted to update the MonoTouch version installed on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the Monotouch folder. After creating it I was prompted to update the MonoTouch version installed on the PC. Fixed it!